# WPF set named style elements from code behind?

Tags: wpf, styles, controltemplate

I have a user control that applies a style to button, with the style containing a ControlTemplate section. Within the ControlTemplate, there are various UI elements such as an Ellipse and a Path.

If I give those elements -- the Ellipse and Path -- a name with x:Name, can I access them from code behind?

It appears the style's Ellipse and Path are not visible because I get a compile error (C#).

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 18):

Because a template can be instantiated multiple times, it's not possible to bind a generated member via `x:Name`.  Instead, you have to find the named element within the template applied to a control.

Given simplified XAML:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate">
    <Ellipse x:Name="MyEllipse" />
</ControlTemplate>
```

You would do something like this:

```
var template = (ControlTemplate)FindResource("MyTemplate");

template.FindName("MyEllipse", myControl);
```

Or even more simply:

```
var ellipse = (Ellipse)myControl.Template.FindName("MyEllipse", myControl);
```

You can read about [`FrameworkTemplate.FindName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworktemplate.findname.aspx).

Some examples and discussion [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613586.aspx), [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/wpfsdk/archive/2007/04/16/how-do-i-programmatically-interact-with-template-generated-elements-part-ii.aspx) and [here](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/06/28/how-to-use-findname-with-a-contentcontrol/).